# Long wait for a retrofit response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm using retrofit in my app and everything is ok except one thing. After disabling internet connection, enabling it back and making request to api (okhttp logger says that GET request was handled), response comes in a few minutes. And when i make next request, response comes immediately.

Also, for the slow response, okhttp logger says that it has been handled in ~50 milliseconds, but prints that log after a few minutes too.

In project i'm using koin, but i doubt it is the root of the problem. Anyway i defined retrofit, okhttpclient and interceptors as single.

And maybe it'll help, if i set read and write timeouts to, for example, 5 seconds in okhttp client i'll get timeout exception.

So what's happening and how to handle with that problem?

`Retrofit`:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client) // my OkHttpClient instance
        .build()
```

`OkHttpClient`:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(networkConnectionInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
        .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build()
```

`NetworkConnectionInterceptor` and `NoConnectivityException` classes:

```
class NetworkConnectionInterceptor(private val context: Context) : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (!isConnected) {
            throw NoConnectivityException()
        }
        val builder: Request.Builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }

    val isConnected: Boolean
        get() {
            val connectivityManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
            val netInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
            return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected
        }
}

class NoConnectivityException : IOException() {
    override val message: String
        get() = "No Internet Connection"
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: @Murat no, haven't found a solution yet